# Airflow REST API - How to get the history of executed tasks?

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-composer

I wants to know the status of all the task executed. We can do that manually, but i wants to know it through REST Client(Google composer).

Answer (score 1):

Composer environment [API](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.environments) currently doesn't support retrieving Airflow-level metadata info. As a workaround, you may want to use Airflow task info[API](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py#L117). Admittedly the Airflow API isn't comprehensive, but if you know the {`dag-id`, `task-id`, `execution-date`} tuple, it might not be a problem. Composer co-hosts the Airflow API server with the webUI, here's an [example](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) on how to programmatically access the Airflow APIs.